# Извлечь подстроку из строки, используя REGEXP_SUBSTR Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть строки
QWER#TYU#111#115
QWER#DFG#11#33
как в данном примере извлечь все значения поле третьего символа '#' с помощью regexp_substr sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом Oracle regex специфический...

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt,'([^#]*#){3}(.*)',1,1,'',2) as substr from Table1
```

[Демо](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59ef4/1)